# Raspberry PiでPyAudioを使ってwaveファイルが正常に鳴らない

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

お世話になります。 
Raspberry PiとPyAudioを使ってwaveファイルを再生すると 
waveファイルの再生時に遅延と音がブチブチ途切れる現象 
が発生しており 
原因を探っております。

以前一度同じような事を試した際は、このような現象は起こっておらず、何か 
音声再生で入れ忘れたライブラリ等がないか探しておりますが 
原因が掴めず、困っております。

以前の設定で、PyAudioの再生の際にALSAのエラーログが 
多数吐き出されていたことを思い出し、ログを漁ったところ 
エラーログに以下の違いがあることは分かっております。（下記に掲載させて頂きます。）

PyAudio再生に使っているコードは、PyAudio Documentationに掲載されている 
「Blocking Mode Audio I/O」 のコードをそのまま使っております。

PyAudioでの再生に使っているコードは、PyAudio Documentationに掲載されている 
「Blocking Mode Audio I/O」 のコードをそのまま使っております。

※ちなみに「Callback Mode Audio I/O」のコードでは問題なく再生されました。 
以前はそちらを使っていないことと、Blocking形式を使って 
再度通常の音を鳴らしたいと考えております。

PyAudioをインストールする際に「Portaudio19-dev」はインストール済みです。

何か不足情報がありましたら御指摘頂ければと思います。 
音声回りの知識が乏しいので、設定で 
何か試すべき事等を御助言頂けるだけでもたすかります。 
こうすれば普通に再生できたという情報もとてもありがたいです。

OS Raspbian Jessie kernel 4.1 
PyAudio Version 0.2.9 
Python 2.7

4/2 追記 --ここから

Raspbianの構築手順を記載いたします。
OSは導入された前提で

rootユーザで以下を実施

```
    #apt-get install portaudio19-dev
    #apt-get install python-dev (updateがかかります)
    #pip install pyaudio
```

home等に環境を作る

```
    # mkdir /home/test
```

gitでソースを持ってくる(githubで公開しております)

```
    # git clone https://github.com/toshift/PyAudio.git
```

cloneした環境で以下を実施 /home/test/Pyaudio とします。

```
    # Python pyaudio_blocking /home/test/Pyaudio/sound/00.wav
    # Python pyaudio_blocking /home/test/Pyaudio/sound/01.wav
```

→これでどちらかで異音がなります。
pyaudio_callbackでは発生しないです。

---ここまで

現在出ているALSAのログ（音が遅延とブチブチ途切れる）

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround40
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround41
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround50
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround51
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

以前普通に再生できていたときのALSAのログ（こちらの方がエラーが多かったです）

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM sysdefault
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround40
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround41
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround50
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround51
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver     returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned     error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4771:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4771:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4771:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM dmix
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
```

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: もし ~/.asoundrc に何か書いてありましたら、質問に記載お願いします。

Comment: コメント頂き有難う御座います。 ~/.asoundrcには何も記述されておりませんでした。

Comment: ちょっと興味があっていじってみています。数値だけを追ってて実際の音を聞かずにあれこれ試してみている状況なのですが、CHUNK=1024 を CHUNK=65536 など大きくすると、症状はいくらか改善する状況ですか?

Comment: コメント頂き有難う御座います！そうですね、CHUNKを例えばそのＷＡＶＥのフレーム数を1回で渡してあげるといくらか音が良くなることは確認できております。
Raspberry Piで構築する方法、手順を本文に掲載させて頂きます！
また、新たに分かったことなのですが、WAVEのチャンネル数が異なるファイルを再生すると症状がわかりやすくなりました。
Channel数1のWav→正常に再生
Channel数2のWav→異音で再生

Comment: マルチポストであればその旨を書きましょう。回答が得られるといいですね。https://teratail.com/questions/31132

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。マルチポストですので今後はその旨記載するようにいたします。御指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: teratail の方に書いてある「以前はそちらを使っていないこと」云々、この辺の記述をこちらの質問にも追記してもらえません? 漏れてますよ。

Comment: 御指摘ありがとうございます。追記致しました！

Comment: 今、LE16 データをそのまま再生していますが、float32 データに変換して再生してやるとどうなるでしょう? `stream.write()` 呼出付近だけでなく `p.open()` の引数も変更してやるる必要がありそうですが。私はまだ python 勉強中の身で、なんとなく読めるけど全然書けない状態なので、やってみてください。お願いします。endian に気をつけてくださいね。

Comment: 根本原因と、Pyaudioを用いて正常に再生できることは確認できなかったですが、別の案で正常再生できることを確認できましたので解決済みとさせて頂きます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

原因は解りませんが、正常な音が鳴るようになったので報告です。

portaudio snapshot において、src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c の 1987行目付近に

```
    self->canMmap = alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_test_access( pcm, hwParams, accessMode ) >= 0 ||
                    alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_test_access( pcm, hwParams, alternateAccessMode ) >= 0;
```

という行があるので、この下に

```
    self->canMmap = 0;
```

を追加し、ビルド、インストールしてください。apt-get でインストールした portaudio はアンインストールしておくのが良いと思います。

流すデータの型は float にしてください。S16 はこれでは正常に鳴りません(頂いた python のテストプログラムで正常に鳴りませんでした)。

私がテストに使ったのは portaudio の paex_write_sine という example です。
上記の修正で正常な音が鳴っていました。
pyaudio からでも、これらの条件を満たせば正常な音が鳴るのではないかと思っています。

ただし、これでもまだたまにブツブツいいますが、その時は、そのプログラムを再起動すれば、次回はきっと正常な音が鳴ります。

私の環境:
raspberry-pi B(たぶん), archlinux arm, kernel 4.1.20, gcc 5.3.0

Comment: 御回答いただきありがとうございます！
さっそく試したいと思います。試した結果につきましては追って報告させていただきます。
前回特に音データを弄っていなかったので、(S16のWaveデータのエンディアン変換をOSSで鳴らしていた時に行っていた位）突然ブチブチなっていたのが不思議でした。

Pyaudioで試す場合は音データを変換する事とportaudioを入れなおす事で問題ないでしょうか。 raspberry-pi Bで間違いございません。

Comment: 御記載頂いた方法を試してみました。S16形式のwav(gitに入れている)はやはり正しく再生できなかったです。最初からfloat形式のwavで一応再生できることは確認できましたが、音データの変換処理を加えるコードを書くより
別途正常に再生できる alsaaudioライブラリで実装できることがわかりましたので、そちらで音声を鳴らすようにしたいと思います。
お忙しい所御回答頂き有難う御座います。